# Which javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType and InheritanceType is best for large ammount of data?

Tags: java, database, performance, jpa, inheritance

I'm about to implement a two level deep inheritance hierarchy of Entities. There will be few millions records in my table(s) that will imported and read. Modification will be rare. Which Discriminator type is best from the performance point of view?

EDIT: And which javax.persistence.InheritanceType has the best performance?

Comment: Can you use an index for the type column? If so, it won't really matter - CHAR/INT are smaller, but the string instances will most likely be shared anyway. If you can't use an index, the queries will probably be faster (at DB level) with CHAR/INT, because the seq scan will have to scan through less data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know what is the best InheritanceType for this scenario?

Comment: Depends on your use case. Single table will perform best if you query for the supertype most often, but doesn't allow NOT NULL columns for subclasses. Table per class will query from multiple tables when not using one of the subtypes, so a query for the supertype will be slightly slower. Joined will fetch from multiple tables for all subtype queries, even for single entities, so that will usually be slowest.

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23037605/2754530)