# Inheritance Mapping in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I was going through the [JPA specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html) on available strategies to map an inheritance relationship to the relational model. I didn't quiet understand the following statements in the spec:

**The Single Table per Class Hierarchy Strategy:**

"This strategy provides good support for polymorphic relationships between entities and queries that cover the entire entity class hierarchy"

**The Table per Concrete Class Strategy**:

"This strategy provides poor support for polymorphic relationships"

Can anyone further clarify the meaning of these statements on how polymorphism is affected by these strategies?

Comment: Single Table per Class Hierarchy - "Designing a proper database schema is too hard!  I'll just put everything into one giant table and call it a day".  Table per Concrete Class - "I like normalization, but I also like performance and don't really care if some information is duplicated".  Joined Subclass - "Normalization is king, I don't care about performance and duplicated data makes me furious".

Comment: @aroth good words really :)

Comment: To put it simple: it's all about _joins_ (in general the more SQL tables are joined the more expensive and slower SQL query is). Apart from very nice answers below take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23037605/2754530) answer for pros / cons and differences between JPA inheritance strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single Table per Class Hierarchy**

this strategy provides a good polymorphic relationships between entity and query is because that JPA can predict what entity is the query for by its `DiscriminatorValue`. example, let say you have an entity like this.

```
select a, b, c, type from table_c;
```

and by using JPA, you can get class A or class B even though you're using table_c and it also easier for you to create a new entity by just adding a new column into that table. (this is what people usually mean by `Denormalisation`)

**Table per Concrete Class**

this strategy provides a poor support for polymorphic relationships is because one table is only for one class. which mean that if you need to create a new entity, then you should create a new table.

Answer (score 4):

Consider we have a domain model as below
[image]

Please study the links provided below.

**[Single Table Strategy](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/)**:

[image]

- All data is stored in single table
- Hence complex joins are not required when retrieving or inserting data
- Polymorphic means multiple entities, in single table, those all are stored in one table. Hence no need for joins
- But this wastes database space as columns need to be nullable
  [single table example](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/)

**[Joined Table Strategy](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-joined-inheritance-example/)**
[image]

- Entity data is stored in separate tables
- Joins are required to insert and retrieve entity data
- Insertion and retrieval becomes heavy because joins are needed
- Saves database space because columns need not be nullable

[Joined table example](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-joined-inheritance-example/)

**[Table per concrete class](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-table-per-concrete-class-example/)**
[image]
 - Again, data is stored in multiple tables hence

[Table per concrete class exmaple](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/17/jpa-table-per-concrete-class-example/)

It all depends on your requirement. If you have ample database and need performance, Single table strategy is the way to go. If you have database constraint, then other strategies are to be followed.

Answer (score 2):

Conside below example.The Table per Concrete Class Strategy

[image]

Here each concrete class is mapped as normal persistent class. so we have 3 tables; PERSON, EMPLOYEE and OWNER to persist the class data. In this  the mapping of the subclass **repeats the properties of the parent class**.

Here you have few disadvantages :

1. if you make any Changes to a parent class is reflected to large number of tables
2. A query couched in terms of parent class is likely to cause a large number of select operations
3. Data thats belongs to a parent class is scattered across a number of subclass tables, which represents concrete classes.

Comment: The way to avoid the repeated data is to use the `JOINED` strategy.  The downside there being that you then need to join multiple tables in order to retrieve a complete record for a subclass entity.  All of the strategies have their various strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: yes, Thats true. it should be used as per requirements only.

Answer (score 0):

See this page, which has examples of each
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/orm/inheritance.html