# How to insert the data in mysql relation table using hibernate/jpa in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have the following schema [image]

First thing is it right ? Like 1 **supplier** has multiple **payments** and supplier has 1 identity that is his **Information**.

I want to insert the payment paid by the supplier.
What I am currently doing is **POST** a json file which has the following elements.

```
{
   "date":"2017-02-17",
   "dueDate":"2018-02-17",
   "payable":2000,
   "paid":1000,
   "supplierId":1
}
```

Now in the controller I am reading the requestJson extracting the **Id** of the supplier and then finding the object of its class and then passing it to the **Payment** for adding the payments. Is this the right way ?

```
case "payment": {

            logger.debug("The condition for the insertion of the payment.");
            try {
                logger.debug("Populating the request Map with the request to identify the type of .");
                requestMap = mapper.readValue(requestBody, Map.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            logger.debug("Identifying the key for the payment is it for customer or supplier.");
            if ((requestMap.containsKey("customerId")) || requestMap.containsKey("pending")){

                logger.debug("The request for the adding payment of the customer has been received.");
                Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(Integer.parseInt(requestMap.get("customerId")));

 //                    Payment payment = new Payment(requestMap.get("dueDate"), requestMap.get("pending"), customer, requestMap.get("data"))
 //                    paymentRepository.save()
            } else if (requestMap.containsKey("supplierId") || requestMap.containsKey("outstanding")){

            }
}
```

Here I have the information model.

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
@Table(name = "Information")
public class Information {

private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String contactNo;

    private String email;

    private String address;

    private Customer customer;

    private Supplier supplier;


    public Information() {
    }

    public Information(String name, String contactNo, String email, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Information(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Information(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "contact_no", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }

    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "information")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "customer-reference")
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "information")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "supplier-reference")
    public Supplier getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Information{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", contactNo='" + contactNo + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Here I have **Customer** there are also some other relations that are associated with this ignore them I want to get the idea.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer") //maps the entity with the table. If no @Table is defined,
// the default value is used: the class name of the entity.
public class Customer {

    private Integer id;

    private Information information;

    private Set<Payment> payments;

    private Set<Sale> sales;

    private Set<Orders> orders;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(Information information) {
        this.information = information;
    }



    /**
     *
     * @return
     */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Information_id")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "customer-reference")
    public Information getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(Information information) {
        this.information = information;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Payment> getPayments() {
        return payments;
    }

    public void setPayments(Set<Payment> payments) {
        this.payments = payments;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CustomerSales", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Customer_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Sale_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Set<Sale> getSales() {
        return sales;
    }

    public void setSales(Set<Sale> sales) {
        this.sales = sales;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Orders> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Customer{id = %d, " +
                "name = %s, " +
                "contact_no = %s, " +
                "address = %s, " +
                "email = %s}",
                id,information.getName(), information.getContactNo(), information.getAddress(), information.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Here is the **Supplier** model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Supplier")
public class Supplier {

    private Integer id;

    private Information information;

    private Set<Payment> payments;

    private Set<Orders> orders;

    private Set<Purchase> purchases;


    public Supplier() {
    }

    public Supplier(Information information) {
        this.information = information;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "InformationId")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "supplier-reference")
    public Information getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(Information information) {
        this.information = information;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Payment> getPayments() {
        return payments;
    }

    public void setPayments(Set<Payment> payments) {
        this.payments = payments;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Orders> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "SupplierPurchases", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Purchase_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public Set<Purchase> getPurchases() {
        return purchases;
    }

    public void setPurchases(Set<Purchase> purchases) {
        this.purchases = purchases;
    }
}
```

And then the last but not least we have **Payment** model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Payment")
public class Payment {

    private Integer id;

    private Date dueDate;

    private Long paid;// When you are in debit you have to pay to supplier

    private Long payable; // When you have to take from customer.

    private Date date;

    private Customer customer;

    private Supplier supplier;

    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

    public Payment() {
    }

    public Payment(Date dueDate, Long payable, Date date, Customer customer, PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.paid = payable;
        this.date = date;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }

    public Payment(Date dueDate, Long paid, Date date, Supplier supplier, PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.paid = paid;
        this.date = date;
        this.supplier = supplier;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }






    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Date getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public void setDueDate(Date dueDate) {
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }

    public Long getPaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void setPaid(Long paid) {
        this.paid = paid;
    }

    public Long getPayable() {
        return payable;
    }

    public void setPayable(Long payable) {
        this.payable = payable;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerId")//mappedBy indicates the entity is the inverse of the relationship.
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SupplierId")
    public Supplier getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PaymentMethodId")
    public PaymentMethod getPaymentMethod() {
        return paymentMethod;
    }

    public void setPaymentMethod(PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Payment{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", dueDate=" + dueDate +
                ", paid=" + paid +
                ", payable=" + payable +
                ", date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
```

Or is there any better way to perform this task?

Gratitude :)

Comment: Do not think in table structure if you are using jpa. You are working with objetcs. So the Relations are modeled there and will be mapped by jpa/hibernate

Comment: @Jens what do you mean by I am not working with the objects ? You want to see the modeled relationships ? Yes I understand the table structure very well its just a part of my schema.

Comment: You have defined entity classes right?  There you build the dependencies between the objects. Can you Show this classes please?

Comment: yes I have defined entity classes I have not shared the code because Its very messy and contains the relation with the other entities as well.

Comment: It's not very easy to say if you approach is correct or not without the entity classes. Perhaps you could post then, editing out all other relations.

Comment: Are you able to change the schema or it's legacy?

Comment: @MartinStraus have a look at code snipets.

Comment: @wypieprz Yeah sure my code my schema I can change anything in schema.

Comment: In what aspect you want a "better" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am reading the requestJson extracting the **Id** of the supplier and then finding the object of its class and then passing it to the **Payment** for adding the payments. Is this the right way ?

Let the Spring framework do the job for you. First modify JSON request a little bit:

```
{
   "date":"2017-02-17",
   "dueDate":"2018-02-17",
   "payable":2000,
   "paid":1000,
   "supplier":{"id":1}
}
```

I can only guess how your REST controller currently looks like, but an example implementation may be as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payment")
public class PaymentController {

    @Autowired
    private final PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    public PaymentController(PaymentRepository paymentRepository) {
        this.paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody Payment payment) {
        paymentRepository.save(payment);
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();

    }
}
```

Such approach results in requested body mapped directly to `Payment` object along with automatically instantiated `Supplier` field so it's enough to save it into the repository then. It's easy to maintain and succint.

Obviously `Customer` and `PaymentMethod` relations are not taken into consideration here but you can easily extend the JSON request to support them.

---

> I have the following schema
>   ...
>   First thing is it right ? Like 1 **Supplier** has multiple **payments** and supplier has 1 identity that is his **Information**.

In general I don't see your schema wrong, but as usual it depends what do you want to achieve. This should definitely work but there are always points such as performance and memory considerations that are impacted by how data are modeled:

- inserting - **Payment** has separate FK for **Customer** and **Supplier** and in fact these two are almost identical (**Sales** vs **Purchases**) so it would probably be better to have one table **Contractor** that aggregates customers and suppliers along with their information
- querying - requesting payments for **Customers** and **Suppliers** along with their **Information** at once, not to mention about their **Orders** or **Sales** / **Purchases**, require multiple joins across hierarchy of tables

Here you can find an alternative approach that leverages JPA inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ContractorType")
public class Contractor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "contact_no", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String contactNo;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private String address;
}
```

The above entity replaces `Customer`, `Supplier` and `Information` entities creating the following table but aggregates their common part only:

```
Contractor
----------
contractor_type  <----  discriminator column for Customer and Supplier
id
name
contact_no          
email           
address
```

The remaining, specific fields (sales, purchases, orders) need to be placed in derived entities let's say `CustomerOperations` and `SupplierOperations`. They create two join tables like before so nothing changes here.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class CustomerOperations extends Contractor {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Payment> payments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Orders> orders;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CustomerSales", 
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Sale_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Sale> sales;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SupplierPurchases ")
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class SupplierPurchases extends Contractor {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Payment> payments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Orders> orders;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "SupplierPurchases", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Purchase_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Purchase> purchases;
}
```

Such approach tends to work faster as the underlying SQL require less joins thus execution plan could be more efficient.

It's worth to mention JPA provides other inheritance strategies. Choosing the right one is not an easy task as each of them has advantages and drawbacks. If you are interested in nuances take a closer look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23037605/2754530).